# ReactJS redirecting to another page on successful statement not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create this single-page-application in react, and I want to redirect to another page based on if the username and password inputs are correct. I have tried multiple approaches, such as the <Redirect to .. tag and history.push(), but none of them seem to be getting rendered. If I try alerts or console.log , I can see that the statement was successful, but the redirect code is never rendered.

This is how my CustomerLoginPage render method looks :

```js
  render() {
    return (
     
        <div class="App-header">
          <NavLink to="/main">
            <button id="backButton">Go Back</button>
          </NavLink>
          <h4>Login with your customer account</h4>
          <br />
          <input id="customerLoginUsername" placeholder=" Username"></input>
          <input id="customerLoginPassword" type="password" placeholder=" Password"></input>
          <br />
          <button id="customerLoginButton" onClick={this.handleSubmit}> 
            Login
          </button>
         
  
          <div className="content"></div>
        </div>
     
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(CustomerLoginPage);
```

And this is how the handleSubmit() looks like :

```js
handleSubmit() {
    
    let usernameInput = document.getElementById('customerLoginUsername');
    let passwordInput = document.getElementById('customerLoginPassword');
  
    if (usernameInput.value !== 'customer' || passwordInput.value !== 'customer') {
      // alert("Wrong username or password!");
    } else {
      this.props.history.replace('/customerhomepage');
    }
  }
```

What could I be missing here? Thanks!

**EDIT**
I managed to fix this issue by changing my CustomerLoginPage from a class component to a function component , and then using useHistory to change the page.
After reading the suggestions about using my Router as a HOC, I removed it from all the files except for index.js and switched to a BrowserRouter instead of HashRouter.

This is how CustomerLoginPage looks now :

```
function CustomerLoginPage () {

  const history = useHistory();

  const loginButtonClicked = () =>{ 
    let path = '/customerhomepage'; 
    history.push(path);
  }

  const backButtonClicked = () => {
    let path = '/main'; 
    history.push(path);
  }

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    
    let usernameInput = document.getElementById('customerLoginUsername');
    let passwordInput = document.getElementById('customerLoginPassword');
  
    if (usernameInput.value !== 'customer' || passwordInput.value !== 'customer') {
      alert("Wrong username or password!");
    } else {
      loginButtonClicked();
    }
  }
  
    return (
     
        <div class="App-header">
  
          <button id="backButton" onClick={backButtonClicked}>Go Back</button>
          <h4>Login with your customer account</h4>
          <br />
          <input id="customerLoginUsername" placeholder=" Username"></input>
          <input id="customerLoginPassword" type="password" placeholder=" Password"></input>
          <br />
          <button id="customerLoginButton" onClick={handleSubmit}> 
            Login
          </button>
         
  
          <div className="content"></div>
        </div>
     
    );
  }

export default withRouter(CustomerLoginPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

1. You can't return JSX from an asynchronous callback and expect it to be rendered and take effect. The `Redirect` ***must*** be rendered in the return of the component.
2. The reason using the `history` object wasn't working is because the `handleSubmit` handler is *outside* the router providing any routing context to navigate against.

## Solution

1. Use the `history` object to issue an imperative redirect.
2. Move the `HashRouter` to wrap `App` and provide a routing context for the `history` object. In fact, you should have only one router wrapping your app to provide the routing context, so remove all other extraneous routers you may have in your app.

Example:

index.js

```
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

...

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App/>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

CustomerHomePage

```
handleSubmit() {
  const usernameInput = document.getElementById("customerLoginUsername");
  const passwordInput = document.getElementById("customerLoginPassword");

  if (usernameInput.value !== "customer" || passwordInput.value !== "customer") {
    // alert("Wrong username or password!");
  } else {
    this.props.history.replace('/customerhomepage');
  }
}
```

Comment: Where and how should I define props?

Comment: @Ruthless `CustomerHomePage` appears to be a class component, so props is already defined on `this.props`. If for some reason the `CustomerHomePage` component isn't being directly rendered by a `Route` component then you can use the [`withRouter`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC to have the `history` object injected as a prop. If `CustomerHomePage` were a function component then you could simply use the [`useHistory`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook.

Comment: I wrapped App with the hashrouter component like in your example, Will this be the HOC that should be used across the application? How can I call this component?

Comment: @Ruthless No, `App` just needs the router above it in the ReactTree so it and anything it's rendering can access the routing context (i.e. the routes, and the route props). If `CustomerHomePage` isn't rendered on a `Route` then this is where the `withRouter` HOC comes into play.

Comment: Ok , do I need to change anything inside App.js? Before my CustomerLoginPage component, I have a Main component with a hashrouter as well. Do I export Main using withRouter? Because I get props undefined typeError when trying to use the history object like in your example

Comment: @Ruthless If you've wrapped your `App` with a `HashRouter` then you should remove all other routers. If I component is expecting to receive route props (i.e. `history`, `location`, and/or `match`) then decorate that component with `withRouter` HOC so they are injected as props. It may be more clear/helpful for you to include your `App`, `Main`, and `CustomerHomePage` components so we can see how they relate.

Comment: Edited my post, added index.js, app.js and Main.js. How should I use the HOC on index.js instead of the router inside the component? do I just export it using withRouter(component)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240200/discussion-between-ruthless-and-drew-reese).

Comment: @Ruthless I responded in chat, but your added edit all looks good except for `Main.js` which needs to have the `HashRouter` removed since there's already a router in `index.js`.

Answer (score 2):

By the time the user clicks on the button and your `handleSubmit` fires, the React component has long since finished rendering, so returning a redirect JSX from the handler won't really have any effect.

If your app architecture supports it (i.e. this isn't an SPA) consider just doing a plain old `window.location.reload` to send the user to the right place.

If not (and I guess you said this is an SPA), you will have to be clever about how to get the `<Redirect>` to get acted upon in the next render. React state might be a good start here... in your else clause, instead of returning the redirect, set some state variable that your render method could check for, and render the `<Redirect>` instead. (Your component is guaranteed to re-render if you change any of its state.)

In other words, modify your render method to either return what it already does, or a `<Redirect>`, depending on the value of a state variable. You can initialize the state to `null` and then have your `handleSubmit` method alter it to, say, the URL you want to redirect to. Then the flow is: render the login page, user provides bad data, your `handleSubmit` sets state saying so, you re-render now as a `<Redirect>` component.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `react-router` I suggest you use the history api to push to the next route.

You can use the withRouter HOC to provide the history api to your props.

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router";


handleSubmit() {
  let usernameInput = document.getElementById('customerLoginUsername');
  let passwordInput = document.getElementById('customerLoginPassword');

  if (usernameInput.value !== 'customer' || passwordInput.value !== 'customer') {
    // alert("Wrong username or password!");
  } else {
    this.props.history.push('/customerhomepage')
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/main" component={Main}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/customerhomepage" component={CustomerHomePage}></Route>
      </Switch>
      <div class="App-header">
        <NavLink to="/main">
          <button id="backButton">Go Back</button>
        </NavLink>
        <h4>Login with your customer account</h4>
        <br />
        <input id="customerLoginUsername" placeholder=" Username"></input>
        <input id="customerLoginPassword" type="password" placeholder=" Password"></input>
        <br />
        <button id="customerLoginButton" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
          Login
        </button>

        <div className="content"></div>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}

export default withRouter(CustomerLoginPage);
```

## Edit:

As other have pointed out, you will need to raise the HashRouter component to a higher component, in order for withRouter to work.